# How to use ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have 3 classes (**Car** (superclass), **CarToRent**, and **CarToSell** (extend Car).

I'm making an interface (CarCompany) and want to store an `ArrayList` of type car in it. How do I do this? Please help?

Comment: An interface can't store anything. It doesn't have any state. It only defines behavior (methods).

Comment: Next time, please don't respond with the same comment to each poster.

Answer (score 3):

In an interface, you can't set attributes because all of them have the final modifier by default, so just declare the `get` and `set` method for your interface. Let that the implementors have the attribute and overrides those methods.

```
public interface CarCompany {
    List<? extends Car> getCarList();
    void setCarList(List<? extends Car> carList);
}
```

UPDATE:

First, you shouldn't use `ArrayList` even if you can, instead use `List` interface, `ArrayList` implements that interface (more info about this: [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)):

```
List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();
```

Second, if you have a superclass, the list attribute shouldn't be for the superclass, instead for a template that supports all that class generation. Let's see a sample of this: you have a DAO class that returns a `List<CarToRent>` and a `List<CarToSell>` in different methods. Later on, in a business class, you need to read all the elements for a `List<Car>` and use the `price` of the car for some formula. Will you create a method to convert from `List<CarToRent>` to `List<Car>` and one for `List<CarToSell>` to `List<Car>`, what if later on you need to create a new child of `Car` like `WreckedCar` for a `CarWorkshop`, will you create a third converter? So, instead of all that pain, you can use the `List<? extends Car>` that do that "dirty work" for you:

```
public void executeSomeFormula(List<? extends Car> carList) {
    //getting the actual VAT value (just for a sample);
    double actualVAT = getActualVATValue();
    //every object in the list extends Car, so it can be threatened as a Car instance
    for(Car car : carList) {
        car.setTotalPrice(car.getPrice() * (1 + actualVAT));
    }
}
```

Comment: It just says "the class CarCompany should store an ArrayList of type Car". What does this mean? Do I use your above code? Thanks so much for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an `ArrayList<CarCompany>` to be able to store every kind of object which comes from a class that implements your `CarCompany` interface.

Comment: It just says "the class CarCompany should store an ArrayList of type Car". What does this mean? Do I use your above code? Thanks so much for helping

Comment: @MissBee You can't store any information in an interface. An interface only defines contracts which you have to implement. Why don't you create/store/manage your cars using Factory design pattern?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

ArrayList<TYPE> al = new ArrayList<TYPE>();
so if you need CarCompany
eg.
ArrayList<CarCompany> al = new ArrayList<CarCompany>();
```

Also have a look at this document about [Class ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: It just says "the class CarCompany should store an ArrayList of type Car". What does this mean? Do I use your above code? Thanks so much for helping

Answer (score 0):

Your `interface` should not have a `List` of cars. It may define getter and setting methods for the `List` but should not define it. Your concrete classes that implement your interface should define the `List`.

```
public class CarCompany{
    private List<Car> myList = new ArrayList<Car>();
}
```

Comment: It just says "the class CarCompany should store an ArrayList of type Car". What does this mean? Do I use your above code? Thanks so much for helping

Comment: Yes. The above `CarCompany` class contains a `List` of `Car` instances.